# C Input and Output

Tags: c

How can you explain the function of this program? and also I cannot understand the mechanism of the used functions?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main()
{
FILE *ptr;
char i;
ptr = fopen("myfile.c", "r");
while((i=fgetc(ptr))!=NULL)
    printf("%c", i);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which part, you did (or did not) understand? If you did not understand the whole program, you sir, are in need of a C book

Comment: "How can you explain ..." Using words? For the functions see any C book or the [C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html).

Comment: Note the code is bugged. If you read about the functions, you should see that yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty basic stuff and a C book is in order.   I like Kernighan and Ritchie's 'The C Programming Language', but pretty much any C book is going to cover all of your program.   Anyway .. Ten lines.   Basically :

- #1 pulls in functions declared in some other file, namely stdio.h
- #2 starts the main program, indicates it has no inputs and will generate a integer number as an output, output is often ignored.
- #3 opens the body of the main
- #4 declares a pointer to a FILE, named ptr, but doesn't set the pointer to point at anything
- #5 declares a character, named i, but doesn't indicate what character i is.
- #6 sets ptr to point to the contents of file 'myfile.c' and tells the OS that we just want to read the file without changing it.
- #7 does a lot.   It starts a loop which will end when we have read a NULL from the file.   That isn't likely to happen as the fgetc program returns EOF instead when it is done reading.   It also sets i to be the next character in the file.
- #8 (still in the loop) prints out the character that is assigned to i (from the file).
- #9 (out of loop) ends the main program function by returning control back to the OS with a return code of 0.
- #10 Technically the end of the main.